# Перевести на с++  одну строчку

Tags: c++

return B ? euclid(B, A % B) : A;
? - к чему он, что за : ?

Comment: Это 

    if (B)
      return euclid(B, A % B);
    else
      return A;

только в одну строчку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

обычный [тернарный оператор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).